# Finding the value of integers of a logarithmic function.

Tags: integration

Expressing $\frac{2x^2-9x-6}{x(x^2-x-6)}$ in partial fraction would give you: $\frac{16}{5(x+2)}$-$\frac{1}{5(x-3)}$-$\frac{1}{x}$

Given that $\int_{4}^6\frac{2x^2-9x-6}{x(x^2-x-6)}dx=ln\frac{m}{n},$ determine the values for the integers m and n.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the partial fraction decomposition is incorrect.

It can be [verified](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282x%5E2%20-%209x%20-%206%29%20%2F%20%28x%28x%5E2%20-%20x%20-%206%29%29%20partial%20fractions) that instead,

$$\begin{align}\int_4^6 \frac{2x^2 - 9x - 6}{x(x^2 - x - 6)} dx &= \int_4^6\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x + 2} - \frac{1}{x-3}dx\\
&=\left[\ln x + 2 \ln (x + 2) - \ln (x - 3)\right]_4^6\\
&= \ln\frac{6}{4} + 2\ln \frac{8}{6} - \ln\frac{3}{1}\\
&= \ln \frac{3}{2} + \ln\frac{16}{9} - \ln 3\\
&= \ln \frac{8}{9}\end{align}$$